# Align fixed-width columns to the decimal point

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, width

I define a new column type for a fixed width column with centre aligned text as follows:

```
\newcolumntype{d}[2]{>{{\rightdots{#1}}r<{\rightdots}\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#2}}
```

The command takes two arguments, {#1} for the number of digits after the decimal point, {#2} for the width of the column.

I then use this column type in a table as follows:

```
\usepackage{array} % for table sizing
\usepackage{booktabs} % for table formatting
\usepackage{dcolumn} % for aligning columns to the decimal point
\usepackage{xfrac} % for slanted fractions
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{d}[2]{>{{\rightdots{#1}}r<{\rightdots}\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#2}}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Processed Data at Blower Frequency of 40 $\left[Hz\right]$}\label{40Hzresults}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{tabular}{C{2.3cm} C{2.3cm} d{3}{2.3cm} C{2.3cm} C{2.3cm} d{3}{2.3cm}}
\toprule
Sphere Size \newline $\left[\textit{mm}\right]$ & Wind Speed \newline $\left[\textit{$\frac{m}{s}$}\right]$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Drag Force \newline $\left[\textit{N}\right]$} & Reynolds Number \newline $\left[\textit{--}\right]$ & Experimental Drag Coefficient \newline $\left[\textit{--}\right]$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Theoretical Drag Coefficient \newline $\left[\textit{--}\right]$} \\
\midrule
64 & 25.66\newline$\pm$0.314 & 0.862 & 108043\newline$\pm$1616.190 & 0.691\newline$\pm$0.060 & 0.455 \\
76 & 25.709\newline$\pm$0.315 & 0.425 & 128544\newline$\pm$1842.879 & 0.241\newline$\pm$0.021 & 0.447 \\
102 & 25.563\newline$\pm$1.16 & 0.313 & 171538\newline$\pm$2337.997 & 0.369\newline$\pm$0.031 & 0.424 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I find that the decimal aligned column does not respect the requested width, and the \newline command does not work. Is this because of the decimal alignment? Is siunitx the only possibility, or is it possible to hardcode this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please put the preamble content and the relevant `\documentclass...` command into your document code above, not splitting it into multiple parts

Comment: What is `\rightdots`? And the column type `C`?

Comment: I found the `\rightdots` command in the documentation for the `array` package.